# How to predict next word in sentence using ngram model in R

Tags: r, nlp, prediction, text-processing, n-gram

I have pre-processed text data into a corpus I would now  like to build a prediction model based on the previous 2 words (so I think a 3-gram model?). Based on my understanding of the articles I have read, here is how I am thinking of doing it:

step 1: enter two word phrase we wish to predict the next word for

```
# phrase our word prediction will be based on
phrase <- "I love"
```

step 2: calculate 3 gram frequencies

```
library(RWeka)

threegramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=3, max=3))

dtm_threegram <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control=list(tokenize=threegramTokenizer))

threegram_freq <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm_threegram)), decreasing = TRUE)
```

The next step is where I am getting stuck. Conceptually, I think I should subset my 3-gram to only include three word combinations that start with "I love". Then, I should only keep the highest frequency 3-gram. For instance, if "I love you" appeared 12 times in my corpus and "I love beer" appeared 15 times, then the probability of "beer" being the next word is higher than "love" hence the model should return the former. Is this the correct approach and if so, how do I create something like this programmatically? My `threegram_freq` object appears to be of numeric class with a character attribute which I don't fully understand what that is. Is it possible to use a regular expression to only include elements starting with "I love" and then extract the 3rd word of the 3-gram with the highest frequency?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using `RWeka` by any chance? Please add the appropriate packages.

Comment: @Axeman I am, see edit. - thanks

Comment: You generally wouldn't use 3-grams to predict next word based on preceding 2-gram. You're looking for advice on model selection. Must you use RWeka, or are you also looking for advice on library? Anyway, this should be migrated to [DataScience.SE](http://http://datascience.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close : migrate to [DataScience.SE](http://http://datascience.stackexchange.com)